# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to use checkboxes for a user to select which items to delete from a DataList. 
This is how I have it coded:

```
protected void deleteItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(DataListItem item in pricing.Items)
    {
        bool IsChecked;
        IsChecked = ((CheckBox)item.FindControl("Delete")).Checked;
        string rowNum = ((Label)item.FindControl("lblRowNum")).Text;

        if (IsChecked)
        {
            //delete each checked item   
            DB.Execute("DELETE FROM ItemWearablePricing WHERE WearablePriceingID = " + rowNum);
        }
    }
}
```

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox'.

I am not exactly sure what I am doing that causes this, though I am sure that someone will point out something that is obvious.

Any help that anyone can offer will be appreciated, thank you. Also, any additional code that may be needed I will do my best to put it up. Thanks to anyone that can help.

And I get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, `item.FindControl("Delete")` is returning a `Button`, not a `CheckBox`.  Double-check the names of your controls.

Comment: yes, I knew it would be something silly that I would of course look over... the checkbox name is really chkDelete.. Thank you for pointing that out. I am not quite sure how I missed it. Will mark answer when the timer allows. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

the "Delete" `id` on the html is related to a `<asp:Button` and not `<asp:CheckBox`